# Wampserver32 is unable to start correctly

Tags: windows, wampserver

I have installed all required microsoft visual c++ redistributable packages required for the installation of wampserver but it is still showing the error message when I try to execute it:- [image]

What can be other possible issue those are causing this?

**N.B. OS is windows 7 64bit**

Comment: Please run `Checks VC++ packages installed` [which can be found at the bottom of this page](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) It will tell you if you have missed any required MSVC runtimes. And it looks like you might have. Probably you forgot that you have to install all the 32bit MSVC runtimes as well as the 64bit ones.

Comment: If that is the case, it is better to uninstall and then reinstall WAMPServer as the install process may also have partly failed without the MSVC runtimes.

Comment: Oh the link I gave is to the WAMPServer Backup Repo and is completely legit

Comment: as a matter of fact, I only installed all 64bit runtimes. do I need to install 32bit runtimes also?

Comment: As I stated, YES, you need the 32bit versions. Specially as it looks like you installed the 32bit version of WAMPServer

Comment: Even is you were using the 64bit WAMPServer the `wampmanager.exe` (the icon in the system tray) is still a 32bit program

Comment: You can also find a link to a zip file containing all the 32bit MSVC runtimes on the aforementioned page. Unzip that somewhere and then run each of the installs one by one

Comment: thanks, I followed everything.checked that all required runtimes are installed using the exe for checking.still no luck.

Comment: Better uninstall WAMPServer. Delete the `wamp\` folder. Now install WAMPServer again from the beginning

Comment: I already did,but failed. I didnt install the MSVC packages as an administrator. does this making any difference? (really stuck in this issue :( )

Comment: I am not sure, I would expect the installs to fail obviously if you tried to install them without the proper permissions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170718/discussion-between-blackcat-and-riggsfolly).